# Sorry, unimplemented: 64 bit mode not compiled in

Tags: c++, windows, mingw-w64

This is what I'm trying to do(on Windows 7 64-bits):

```
g++ -m64 -o main main.cpp
```

And the error I get is:

```
Sorry, unimplemented: 64 bit mode not compiled in ...
```

I installed mingw-64-install.exe from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/

But I still get the same error. Do I also need to add the path to this folder in the environment variable?

This is what I get when I type `g++ -v`:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-4.9.3/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu    --host=m
ingw32 --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i58
6 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --enable-static --enable-sha
red --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable- version-sp
ecific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-nls
 Thread model: win32​
 gcc version 4.9.3 <GCC>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When running `mingw-64-install.exe`, you have to choose the `x86_64` architecture on the settings screen. With this architecture, 64-bit is also the default target. If you run `g++ -v`, you should get something like:

```
C:\>g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/Program\ Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-5.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-5.3.0/configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw64 --with-sysroot=/c/mingw530/x86_64-530-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64 --with-gxx-include-dir=/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++ --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp --enable-libatomic --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-checking=release --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --disable-isl-version-check --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-bootstrap --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-arch=nocona --with-tune=core2 --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/c/mingw530/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpfr=/c/mingw530/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpc=/c/mingw530/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-isl=/c/mingw530/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-pkgversion='x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project' --with-bugurl=http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64 CFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -I/c/mingw530/x86_64-530-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw530/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw530/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -I/c/mingw530/x86_64-530-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/opt/include -I/c/mingw530/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/c/mingw530/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CPPFLAGS= LDFLAGS='-pipe -L/c/mingw530/x86_64-530-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0/mingw64/opt/lib -L/c/mingw530/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/lib -L/c/mingw530/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/lib '
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.3.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
```

The *Target* line should say `x86_64`.

Comment: First I chose x86_64, but it didn't work. Then I redo the installation with i686(without deleting the previous installation with x86_64), but it doesn't work

Comment: And I also I forgot to specify that I have also installed the 32-bit version before. That I have not deleted yet.

Comment: @lads What do you mean by "it didn't work"? What's the output of `g++ -v`?

Comment: I think the problem is that I have installed MinGw 32 bit before installing the MinGW 64 bit and when I use g++ it goes to the 32 bit version. When I run g++ -v I have Target: win32

Comment: @lads The executable is the same for both, so there's no way the shell can know which one you're trying to execute. Either use the full path to the executable, or get rid of the 32-bit version. Or just have two different environments with two separate PATHs, one for 32-bit and another for 64-bit.

Comment: @Luaan as you can see in COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER I have different path than nwellnhof which is the path where I have my 32 bit Mingw if I go to the path given in the nwellnhof answer I can find the x86_64-w64-mingw32.exe. But I don't know how can I change this path

Comment: @lads How do you launch your MinGW shell? Did you try to run `C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-5.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0\mingw-w64.bat` directly?

Comment: @nwellnhof Oh you are right. Thanks. Before I just launched the cmd window. But now I get a weird error `g++ -m64 main.cpp -o main.exe`  http://pastebin.com/wjBtFv5c

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem with Windows 10 Home / AMD Ryzen 5 3400G.

For some reason the `mingw64` install program decided for host `i686-8.1.0-win32-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0`

Solution was copying the mingw64 `x86_64-w64-mingw32` installation from another notebook.