# MinGW install on offline Windows for Matlab R2018a

Tags: windows, matlab, mingw, mingw-w64

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38393755/mingw-w64-offline-installer) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028808/is-there-an-offline-mingw-installer). The list [goes on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45073791/how-to-install-mingw-w64-c-c-compiler-for-use-in-matlab-2016b).

However, I need to install MinGW (preferably the latest version) in a Windows machine which is purposefully isolated from the internet. The purpose is to use soem features of Matlab 2018b that require a compiler. I can upload files to it within some restrictions, but I can neither use the default MinGW installer, nor can I use the "Get Add-On" menu command.

By the way, the machine works with windows server.

How can I get an installer or a set of files that would allow me to install MinGW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For versions 2016b and newer, MathWorks provides a tool that allows downloading support packages and sending them to off-line environments. [The tool can be downloaded here](https://www.mathworks.com/support/install/support-software-downloader.html?s_tid=srchtitle) and will require admin permission to install. With it, you can select packages to download at a target folder, and later transfer them to the off-line environment.

For each package there will be a readme file with the relevant instructions.